# Pointers and strings

Tags: c++, pointers

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char *a[10];          //an array of ptrs
    cin>>a[0];            //Entering first input
    cin>>a[1];            //Entering second input
}
```

I get an error after entering the first input.
Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: I advice you to go through a basic tutorial..

Comment: It's C++.. Why not simply `std::string`?..

Comment: Well the error that i get  is bad access thread

Answer (score 5):

You don't have memory allocated to hold the resulting data. Use `std::string` instead of `char*` until you understand how C strings work and really need them.

Comment: To clarify MvG's answer, your code should look like `std::string a[10];`